# Can't Add Custom Meta Box to Custom Post Type

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-post-type

Trying to add a custom meta box to a custom post type in wordpress and nothing seems to work.

When I copy and paste a whole code snippet from tutorials it works just fine. When I try and add it to my already made custom post type, I get nothing. The page doesn't break, the custom meta box just doesn't display. Would love some help as I'm pulling my hair out.

At this point, I just want the darn thing to show up in the post editing interface!

```
// Register Custom Post Type
function generate_shows() {

  $labels = array(
    'name'                => _x( 'Shows', 'Post Type General Name', 'text_domain' ),
    'singular_name'       => _x( 'Show', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'text_domain' ),
    'menu_name'           => __( 'Shows', 'text_domain' ),
    'parent_item_colon'   => __( 'Parent Item:', 'text_domain' ),
    'all_items'           => __( 'All Shows', 'text_domain' ),
    'view_item'           => __( 'View Item', 'text_domain' ),
    'add_new_item'        => __( 'Add New Show', 'text_domain' ),
    'add_new'             => __( 'Add New', 'text_domain' ),
    'edit_item'           => __( 'Edit Item', 'text_domain' ),
    'update_item'         => __( 'Update Item', 'text_domain' ),
    'search_items'        => __( 'Search Shows', 'text_domain' ),
    'not_found'           => __( 'Not found', 'text_domain' ),
    'not_found_in_trash'  => __( 'Not found in Trash', 'text_domain' )
  );
  $args = array(
    'label'               => __( 'enk_show', 'text_domain' ),
    'description'         => __( 'An individual ENK Shows', 'text_domain' ),
    'labels'              => $labels,
    'supports'            => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'revisions', 'custom-fields', 'page-attributes', 'post-formats', ),
    'taxonomies'          => array( 'category', 'post_tag' ),
    'hierarchical'        => true,
    'rewrite'             => array( 'slug' => 'shows', 'with_front' => false ),
    'public'              => true,
    'show_ui'             => true,
    'show_in_menu'        => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
    'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
    'menu_position'       => 5,
    'can_export'          => true,
    'has_archive'         => true,
    'exclude_from_search' => false,
    'publicly_queryable'  => true,
    'register_meta_box_cb' => 'add_enk_metaboxes',
    'capability_type'     => 'post'
  );
  register_post_type( 'enk_show', $args );

}

// Hook into the 'init' action
add_action( 'init', 'generate_shows', 0 );


// Add the Events Meta Boxes
function add_enk_metaboxes() {
  add_meta_box('wpt_events_location', 'Event Location', 'wpt_events_location', 'events', 'side', 'default');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'add_enk_metaboxes')
```

You also need to create a function for the html for the box

e.g.

```
function wpt_events_location($post) { // your 3rd parameter is the function callback
     $metavalue= get_post_meta($post->id,'metakey',true);
     echo '<input type="text" name="formfield" value="'.$metavalue.'" >';
}
```

and a callback to save

```
function save_post_meta($post_id){
  if($_POST['formfield'])
  update_post_meta($post_id,'metakey',$_POST['formfield'];

}

add_action('save_post', 'save_post_meta');
```

The codex has some good examples as i remember including nonces and OOP style. PS note there is no security above, you still need to sanitize values etc.

Answer (score 0):

You Must try this:

First you create a meta box for your post type

```
<?php    
// Add the Events Meta Boxes
    function add_enk_metaboxes($post) {
      add_meta_box('wpt_events_location', 'Event Location', 'wpt_events_location', 'events', 'side', 'default');
    }
    add_action('add_meta_boxes','add_enk_metaboxes');
```

Then you make a function for meta fields:

```
function wpt_events_location($post){

    $txtEventLocation = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'txtEventLocation', true);
?>
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="4" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
            <td width="16%">
                <strong>Event Location:</strong>
            </td>
            <td width="84%">
                <input type="text" name="txtEventLocation" id="txtEventLocation" size="72%" value="<?php echo $txtEventLocation ?>" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
<?php
}
```

Then you save the meta field data:

```
add_action('save_post','save_event_location');
function save_event_location(){
    global $post;

    $txtEventLocation = $_POST['txtEventLocation'];

    update_post_meta( $post->ID, 'txtEventLocation', $txtEventLocation);
}

?>
```

Hope you find your solution.

Comment: Quick question, on line 2 of `wpt_events_location` where are you getting the meta key name `txtEventLocation`? I don't see you use it in the other functions?

Comment: `wpt_events_location` is a id of meta box its never used ... its only for uniqueness ... Please can you tell me, what do you mean that (where are you getting the meta key name txtEventLocation)

Comment: You've not made a reference to it? So I'm a little confused as to where that string came from and how it's getting the meta value?

Comment: in which part ... bro please look properly

Comment: Sorry XD `get_post_meta` 2nd attribute is to be the key, so wouldn't that be `wp_events_location`? :S

Comment: OK! I think I've got it! Is it the input field? I thought `wpt_events_location` was for the DOM loop bit thingy :d sorry XD

Answer (score 0):

Code will help you to create custom metabox in wordpress

```
<?php

add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'add_custom_metaboxes' );


// Add the Events Meta Boxes

function add_custom_metaboxes() {
    //add_meta_box('wpt_events_date', 'Event Date', 'wpt_events_date', 'wpstore', 'side', 'default');
    add_meta_box('wpt_events_location', 'Address Location', 'wpt_events_location', 'post_tyme_name', 'normal', 'high');
}

// The Event Location Metabox

function wpt_events_location() {
    global $post;

    // Noncename needed to verify where the data originated
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="eventmeta_noncename" id="eventmeta_noncename" value="' . 
    wp_create_nonce( plugin_basename(__FILE__) ) . '" />';

    // Get the location data if its already been entered
    $addressline1 = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_addressline1', true);
    $addressline2 = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_addressline2', true);


    // Echo out the field
        echo '<p>Address Line 1:</p>';
        echo '<input type="text" name="_addressline1" value="' . $addressline1  . '" class="widefat" />';
        echo '<p>Address Line 2</p>';
        echo '<input type="text" name="_addressline2" value="' . $addressline2  . '" class="widefat" />';
}


// Save the Metabox Data

function wpt_save_events_meta($post_id, $post) {

    // verify this came from the our screen and with proper authorization,
    // because save_post can be triggered at other times
    if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['eventmeta_noncename'], plugin_basename(__FILE__) )) {
    return $post->ID;
    }

    // Is the user allowed to edit the post or page?
    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post->ID ))
        return $post->ID;

    // OK, we're authenticated: we need to find and save the data
    // We'll put it into an array to make it easier to loop though.

    $events_meta['_addressline1'] = $_POST['_addressline1'];
    $events_meta['_addressline2'] = $_POST['_addressline2'];

    // Add values of $events_meta as custom fields

    foreach ($events_meta as $key => $value) { // Cycle through the $events_meta array!
        if( $post->post_type == 'revision' ) return; // Don't store custom data twice
        $value = implode(',', (array)$value); // If $value is an array, make it a CSV (unlikely)
        if(get_post_meta($post->ID, $key, FALSE)) { // If the custom field already has a value
            update_post_meta($post->ID, $key, $value);
        } else { // If the custom field doesn't have a value
            add_post_meta($post->ID, $key, $value);
        }
        if(!$value) delete_post_meta($post->ID, $key); // Delete if blank
    }

}

add_action('save_post', 'wpt_save_events_meta', 1, 2); // save the custom fields
```